# Parent Included in Google App Engine Entity Groups

Tags: google-app-engine, entity-groups

Short question:

Is the parent of an entity group included in that entity group (i.e. can a transaction affect the parent of an entity as well as the entity itself)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Short answer :)